# Pass json data of listview to next activity on click of row item

Tags: android, json, listview

I need to pass the json data of listview to the next activity on the click of row item.

here is my first Activity

```
public class DrSearch extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    OnItemClickListener {
    ListView listView;

    ArrayList<RowItem> rowDoctors;

    DrSearchListViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dr_search);

        iv.setOnClickListener(this);
        rowDoctors = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        new DoctorList().execute();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        adapter = new DrSearchListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.single_list_dr_search, rowDoctors);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        int actualDataPosition=adapter.getActualPosition(position, rowDoctors);


        if(actualDataPosition>=0)
        {
            String data=rowDoctors.get(actualDataPosition).getId()+","+rowDoctors.get(actualDataPosition).getImageId()+","+rowDoctors.get(actualDataPosition).getTitle();

            Intent newActivity = new Intent(DrSearch.this, DocProfileForUser.class);   

            newActivity.putExtra("Position", actualDataPosition);
            newActivity.putExtra("data", data);
             startActivity(newActivity);
        }

    }

    }
    class DoctorList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        private String Content;
        private String Error = null;
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(DrSearch.this);
        String data = "";

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
            Dialog.show();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {




            // To retrieve value from shared preference in another activity
            SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext()

                    .getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefName", 0); 

            String user_id = sp.getString("key_name", "defaultvalue"); 

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token",
                    "testermanishrahul234142test"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", user_id));

            Content = new ServiceHandler().makeServiceCall(
                    AppConstant.GET_DOCTOR_LIST, 2, nameValuePairs);
            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Dialog.dismiss();



            String OutputData = "";
            JSONObject jsonResponse;

            try {


                jsonResponse = new JSONObject(Content);


                JSONObject jsonMainNode = jsonResponse
                        .getJSONObject("document");

                JSONObject response = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject("response");

                JSONArray jarray = response.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    RowItem list = new RowItem();

                    list.setAvailability(object.getString("morning_appointment_start"));
                    list.setAvailability1(object.getString("morning_appointment_end"));
                    list.setAvailability2(object.getString("eve_appointment_start"));
                    list.setAvailability3(object.getString("eve_appointment_end"));
                    list.setTitle(object.getString("firstName"));
                    list.setSpeciality(object.getString("speciality"));
                    list.setImageId(object.getString("image"));
                    list.setId(object.getString("id"));

                    rowDoctors.add(list);


                }


                String status = response.getString("status");
                if (status != null && status.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                }
                String message = response.getString("message");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "" + status + ":" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();





            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }




        }
    }


}
```

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: What's the Error ?

Comment: how to set this in second activity

Comment: int actualDataPosition=adapter.getActualPosition(position, rowDoctors);


    if(actualDataPosition>=0)
    {

        String data=rowDoctors.get(actualDataPosition).getId()+","+rowDoctors.get(actualDataPosition).getImageId()+","+rowDoctors.get(actualDataPosition).getTitle();

        Intent newActivity = new Intent(DrSearch.this, DocProfileForUser.class);   

        newActivity.putExtra("Position", actualDataPosition);
        newActivity.putExtra("data", data);
         startActivity(newActivity);
    }

Comment: i am using this in second activity

Comment: try
  {
  position=getIntent().getIntExtra("Position",0);
  data=getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
  
  
 
  
  
  if(data.contains( ","))
  {
   String actualDataPosition;                 
 String[] userData=data.split( rowDoctors.get(actualDataPosition).getTitle()",");
   for (String item : userData)
   {
       System.out.println("item = " + item);
   }
  }
  
  }

Comment: how to do this any solution please . i am new in android

Comment: Post your second activity class whole code here.

Answer (score 0):

Passing Data:

```
 Intent newActivity = new Intent(DrSearch.this, DocProfileForUser.class);   
        newActivity.putExtra("data", data);
        startActivity(newActivity);
```

Receiving Data in Second Activity:

```
    String dataString;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
      if(extras != null) {
        dataString= extras.getString("data");
      }

TextView tvData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_data);
tvData.setText(dataString);
```

Comment: and how to set data to textview and imageView in second activity

Comment: Need to do like this  try { position=getIntent().getIntExtra("Position",0); data=getIntent().getStringExtra("data"); if(data.contains( ",")) { String actualDataPosition; String[] userData=data.split( rowDoctors.get(actualDataPosition).getTitle()","); for (String item : userData) { System.out.println("item = " + item); } } }  as he said in my post read it @AsimKrishnaDas

Comment: @ Asim Krishna Das sir using your answer , it is setting whole url to the text view

Answer (score 0):

Convert your data to Json format and then send it to second activity like this:

```
String data = "{'id : '"+rowDoctors.get(actualDataPosition).getId()+"', 'image_id':'"+rowDoctors.get(actualDataPosition).getImageId()+"', 'title':'"+rowDoctors.get(actualDataPosition).getTitle()+"'}";

Intent newActivity = new Intent(DrSearch.this, DocProfileForUser.class);
newActivity.putExtra("data", data);
startActivity(newActivity);
```

Get the JsonObject back from second activity like this:

```
String data;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null) {
data= extras.getString("data");
}

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
```

Comment: this is my json
{
  "document": {
    "response": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "4",
          "firstName": "Adam "
          "image": "http://69.73.184.155/~isoft/doctorApp/web_serv/uploads/doctor/1456375493img1.jpg",
          "doctor_id": "4"
        },
        {
          "id": "8",
          "firstName": "Dr. Mark",
          "lastName": "Mark",
          "image": "http://69.73.184.155/~isoft/doctorApp/web_serv/uploads/doctor/145451353012606908_10156490446530338_535014725_n.jpg"
          "doctor_id": "8"
        }

Comment: your solution is setting all the fields to the textview